# Problema com Angular ui.bootstrap.modal

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap

Iniciando um modal com ui.bootstrap.modal $uibModal, setei controller e controllerAs, no console.log vejo que o controller da instancia foi iniciado e o objeto carregado quando clicado, mas dentro da modal nao consigo exibir os dados, alguém pode ajudar?

http://plnkr.co/edit/CK41JbKVjxUuZrAM3tNy?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

O erro era causado pelo seu `WindowTemplate`que estava gerando um `$scope` e por isso no HTML do modal a sua `vm` não era acessível.

**Em index.html**

Substitua a linha:

```
<script src="https://admin.marciodias.me/node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Por:

```
<script src="https://admin.marciodias.me/node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

No seu `ng-template` do modal remova as divs `<div class="inmodal">` e           `<div class="modal-dialog">`

**No controller.js**

Remova a linha:

```
windowTemplateUrl: 'modal-retailchain-product-edit.tpl.html',
```

Feito isso é só acessar a vm no html do modal.

Comment: não solucionado, adicionei o ambiente ao plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/CK41JbKVjxUuZrAM3tNy?p=preview